# Using Images and Icons in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, icons

I am trying to use an Icon in my WPF application, and some images for other things, but I keep getting errors from the Designer View saying stuff like "path-x is not a valid resource or cannot be found." - where "path-x" is the path of whatever image I am trying to use.

If it were looking in the right place, I bet it'd find it ;)

BUT, then, it decided to not give me that error anymore. So, I went ahead and clicked Run (F5), to see my new Icon in the title bar. Only to be confronted with this beast:

> "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>   occurred   Message='Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension'
>   threw an exception.' Line number '5'
>   and line position '50'.
>   Source=PresentationFramework
>   LineNumber=5   LinePosition=50
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception
>   e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri
>   baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory
>   writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object
>   rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object
>   rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream
>   stream, ParserContext parserContext,
>   Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>          at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator)
>          at One_Stop_Management.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()
>   in c:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\One Stop
>   Management\One Stop
>   Management\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
>          at One_Stop_Management.MainWindow..ctor()
>   in C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\One Stop
>   Management\One Stop
>   Management\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 25 
>   InnerException: System.IO.IOException
>          Message=Cannot locate resource 'images/favicon.ico'.
>          Source=PresentationFramework
>          StackTrace:
>               at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access)
>               at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access)
>               at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
>               at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
>               at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
>               at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption
>   cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean&
>   isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream,
>   UnmanagedMemoryStream&
>   unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle&
>   safeFilehandle)
>               at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream,
>   BitmapCreateOptions createOptions,
>   BitmapCacheOption cacheOption,
>   RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy,
>   Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
>               at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream,
>   BitmapCreateOptions createOptions,
>   BitmapCacheOption cacheOption,
>   RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
>               at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object
>   value)
>               at System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension
>   me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>          InnerException:  "

[image: Exception at runtime while trying to use an icon for my titlebar!]

Why is this thing giving me attitude? I'm just trying to insert an image...

## Updates

Here is the XAML that was produced for the icon when I tried to add the Icon using the Properties Pane:

```
<Fluent:RibbonWindow x:Class="One_Stop_Management.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"
        Title="One Stop Management" Height="727" Width="1208" Icon="Resources\favicon.ico">
```

## Latest Update

[image]

I can't even add an icon using the properties pane, below is the error it gives me.

Comment: Can you share the XAML where you are trying to insert the image?

Comment: Yeah sure. I am updating now.

Comment: @Craig, added it to bottom of question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you *all* for your help! I have figured out what the heck was going on after reading @Craig's link to MS Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't be more helpful.  On reading your question at first I thought it'd be just a type mismatch, like where you were specifying a string when it was meant to be an image.  The issue seems to be one that has multiple possible resolutions.  Instead of listing them all I'll just link you to the [Microsoft Connect page that has them on it](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533882/provide-value-on-system-windows-baml2006-typeconvertermarkupextension-threw-an-exception).

Comment: Although this is an old thread, I would like to add my findings. It turns out that XP can handle correctly icons with 256x256 with 32 bits color depth. After removing this image format from the ico the exception didn't happen again.

Comment: Craig the link is dead

Comment: Link only answer is not very helpful unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the target is a resource.  Then do something like this:

```
Icon="/MobilWPF;component/Resources/Images/MobileIcon.ico"
```

where MobilWPF is your namespace, or maybe you're project name?  I forget my project name and my namespace are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered that VS2008 sometimes causes problems like this when you add new resources and then rebuild the project.   I've found if you clean the build and then rebuild from scratch the problem disappears.   Looks like a VS2008 bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this same issue by setting these properties for the image:

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Directory = Copy always
```

Comment: Just a comment comparing with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241279/774575): When using a file in a project, either you embed this file in the assembly at compile time (Build Action = Resource), or you deploy the file independently (Build Action = Content **and** Copy to Output = Copy Always/If Newer). In both cases the file content is accessible at run time. Each method has its pros and cons, in your case, the assembly is smaller, but the access time is longer (and the separate file must exist).

Answer (score 1):

The exception, if you read through it, says the same thing:

> InnerException: System.IO.IOException Message=Cannot locate resource 'images/favicon.ico'.

This is probably because the `Images/favicon.ico` icon image is not setup correctly.  Make sure that it's Build Action is set to "Resource", and that it's in the project under the "Images" folder.

Comment: Yeah, I read it. It IS there, in the Images folder. I think there's a bug somewhere though in WPF or Visual Studio or something, because the file is there, the string path is correct, the folder is there. But it's just not finding it. I don't know how you can not find something that is right infront of you.

Comment: Visual Studio auto creates a folder called "Images" with a capital "I". But when I get the error, the error as a lower case "i". So i even tried changing the I in the Images folder to a lowercase one. Still didn't work.

Comment: @ βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ: Did you check the Build Action (right click on the icon file in VS, choose Properties)?  It should be "Resource"

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to depend on where/how you store the icon. I was trying to do something similar to [@iterationx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471597/149259) but it didn't work for me, and this is what I finished up with. I'm using VS 2010.

I added the icon as a resource via the project's properties page, under Resources, Add Resource (dropdown), Add existing file. Then I just used the file name in the `Icon` property:

```
Icon="my_icon.ico"
```

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 Community and this still helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I recall a similar situation where my application was crashing, and I eventually tracked it down to an .ico error.

If you're using icons and Windows XP, XP does not support the 256x256 icons.  You may need to open the icon in an editor, such as IcoFx, and delete the 256x256 icon.

Comment: I got into the same issue today. I deleted the 256x256 icon using VS 2012 (Right click > Delete Image Type) and it worked fine on XP.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `BuildAction` to `Resource` in resource `Properties` solved this problem.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found that if your project has a space in the name, it won't read the image files correctly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use Icon=".\Images\test.ico" this got me working

Comment: If you could give some more information it could help understand your aproche better

Comment: when you are trying to add a icon to your application, you often find this error message. So to overcome the problem you are gonna have to use the Icon=".\Images\test.ico" as the code.

Comment: okay i see, I would have to add this line into the SourceCode. Thanks for the update