# Setting the Source of a WPF Image Control at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an Image control in a WPF Window named "Image1". I am trying to set the picture that is displayed with a png file that I added as a resource.

I am really struggling to figure out how to do it.

I am using VB.Net and I am new to it.

EDIT: I found this while waiting for help:

```
Image1.Source = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri("/images/imagenamehere", UriKind.Relative))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9471597/73804

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your images to a folder named `images` in the root of your project using the *Add Existing Item* command in Visual Studio, then you can reference your images in a simpler way than you have displayed in your edit. There is no need to use a `BitMapImage` either. You can set the `Image.Source` property, either at design time, or at runtime like this:

```
Image.Source = "/ApplicationName;component/images/ImageName.png";
```

Although, I'd like to add that in WPF, the best way to set an `Image.Source` at runtime is with a `Binding`. In this respect, you'd change the `string` property that was data bound to the `Image.Source` property to the above `string` to change the image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set the icon property of a window like mentioned above but it returned an error. I search and found a solution. I don't know if it is the best solution but maybe someone has got the same problem.

Solution:

```
windowX.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(New Uri("Resources\addX.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream)
```